# Google Analytics Real Time Events Aren't Being Captured with Angular

Tags: angularjs, google-analytics

I've got a tracking code installed, in my development environment. I include the debug version of analytics, and I am sending events in some angular functions. Here's an example:

```
            window.ga_debug = {trace: true};
            ga('send', {
              hitType: 'event',
              eventCategory: 'Freelancer Application',
              eventAction: 'submit',
              eventLabel: 'Role'
            });
```

Using the debugger, I can see the event is being sent, and that the request is successful. See below for the debug output. However, the events show up almost never, intermittently, without any code change. One thing to note, my domain in my local environment doesn't match the registered domain on GA, but as far as I can tell that's not what's causing this issue.

```
    Executing Google Analytics commands.
    analytics_debug.js:9 Running command: ga("send", {hitType: "event", eventCategory: "Freelancer Application", eventAction: "submit", eventLabel: "Info"})
    analytics_debug.js:9 Send start: 402598
    analytics_debug.js:9   hitType="event" (temp)
    analytics_debug.js:9   eventCategory="Freelancer Application" (temp)
    analytics_debug.js:9   eventAction="submit" (temp)
    analytics_debug.js:9   eventLabel="Info" (temp)
    analytics_debug.js:9 
    Executing 15 filters:
    analytics_debug.js:9   filter[0]: _oot
    analytics_debug.js:9   filter[1]: previewTask
    analytics_debug.js:9   filter[2]: checkProtocolTask
    analytics_debug.js:9   filter[3]: validationTask
    analytics_debug.js:9   filter[4]: checkStorageTask
    analytics_debug.js:9   filter[5]: historyImportTask
    analytics_debug.js:9   filter[6]: samplerTask
    analytics_debug.js:9   filter[7]: _rlt
    analytics_debug.js:9   _ti=1464201475750
    analytics_debug.js:9   _to=19
    analytics_debug.js:9   _hc=4
    analytics_debug.js:9   filter[8]: ceTask
    analytics_debug.js:9   filter[9]: devIdTask
    analytics_debug.js:9   filter[10]: displayFeaturesTask
    analytics_debug.js:9   _um=[undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, true]
    analytics_debug.js:9   _j1="" (temp)
    analytics_debug.js:9   filter[11]: buildHitTask
    analytics_debug.js:9   usage="CACAAMABI~" (temp)
    analytics_debug.js:9   _s=4
    analytics_debug.js:9   hitPayload="v=1&_v=j43d&a=1869146530&t=event&_s=4&dl=http%3A%2F%2Fnuno%2Fapp.html&ul=en-us&de=UTF-8&dt=Clementine&sd=24-bit&sr=1920x1200&vp=1671x467&je=0&fl=21.0%20r0&ec=Freelancer%20Application&ea=submit&el=Info&_u=CACAAMABI~&jid=&cid=2130340064.1464195843&tid=UA-78296064-2&z=1203210418" (temp)
    analytics_debug.js:9   filter[12]: _dt
    analytics_debug.js:9   filter[13]: sendHitTask
    analytics_debug.js:9 
    Sent beacon:
    v=1&_v=j43d&a=1869146530&t=event&_s=4&dl=http%3A%2F%2Fnuno%2Fapp.html&ul=en-us&de=UTF-8&dt=Clementine&sd=24-bit&sr=1920x1200&vp=1671x467&je=0&fl=21.0%20r0&ec=Freelancer%20Application&ea=submit&el=Info&_u=CACAAMABI~&jid=&cid=2130340064.1464195843&tid=UA-78296064-2&z=1203210418


    analytics_debug.js:9 _j1              (&jid) 
    analytics_debug.js:9 adSenseId        (&a)   1869146530
    analytics_debug.js:9 apiVersion       (&v)   1
    analytics_debug.js:9 clientId         (&cid) 2130340064.1464195843
    analytics_debug.js:9 encoding         (&de)  UTF-8
    analytics_debug.js:9 eventAction      (&ea)  submit
    analytics_debug.js:9 eventCategory    (&ec)  Freelancer Application
    analytics_debug.js:9 eventLabel       (&el)  Info
    analytics_debug.js:9 flashVersion     (&fl)  21.0 r0
    analytics_debug.js:9 hitType          (&t)   event
    analytics_debug.js:9 javaEnabled      (&je)  0
    analytics_debug.js:9 language         (&ul)  en-us
    analytics_debug.js:9 location         (&dl)  http://nuno/app.html
    analytics_debug.js:9 screenColors     (&sd)  24-bit
    analytics_debug.js:9 screenResolution (&sr)  1920x1200
    analytics_debug.js:9 title            (&dt)  Clementine
    analytics_debug.js:9 trackingId       (&tid) UA-78296064-2
    analytics_debug.js:9 viewportSize     (&vp)  1671x467
    analytics_debug.js:9   hitCallback=[function] (temp)
    analytics_debug.js:9   filter[14]: timingTask
    analytics_debug.js:9 Send finished: 402631
```

Comment: I copied the payload string from your debug output, substituted my own UAID and pasted in to the browser - as expected the event showed up.  Is there something configured on the receiving end (filters maybe) that could interfere with your events ?

Comment: @EikePierstorff Weird - this is a brand new GA account, no filters applied at all.

Comment: I'm a bit puzzled that your hit is send - "nuno/app.html" is not a fully qualified domain name (misses a TLD), I would not have thought that GA can set a cookie here and without cookie it would usually abort. But then the debugger shows that the hit has been sent. You said specifically "realtime" - did the hits eventually show up in the "permanent" reports ?

Comment: @EikePierstorff it's a new account, nothing has shown up in permanent records. according to GA docs "analytics.js does not require setting cookies to transmit data to Google Analytics." https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/cookie-usage#analyticsjs

Comment: Google does not require cookies, but if you do not want to use them you have to set storage to none, and then you won't have sessions unless you pass in the clientid yourself. The js tracker usually balks out if it cannot set a cookie, that's why I was wondering (this is checked in the checkStoragetask https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/tasks#overview, if you are interested). Can you send a few hits via the console simply to confirm that hits arrive at all ?

Comment: @EikePierstorff when i send hits from the console some of them do arrive, but most of them do not

Comment: Would it be okay if I send a few hits from my side (if the id in the debug output is your real one), so we can rule out that the problem is somewhere with your network.